# Can't connect to socketio/express server

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, peerjs

I am following a tutorial on a zoom clone with nodejs but I get errors (in the web console):

```
websocket.js:87 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3030/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=on90y1WuFetxiRq0AAAC' failed: Invalid frame header
```

and

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

(server.js):

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    // const cors = require('cors')
    // app.use(cors())
    const server = require("http").Server(app);
    const io = require("socket.io")(server);
    const { ExpressPeerServer } = require("peer");
    const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
      debug: true,
    });
    const { v4: uuidV4 } = require("uuid");
    
    app.use("/peerjs", peerServer);
    
    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.use(express.static("public"));
    
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`);
    });
    
    app.get("/:room", (req, res) => {
      res.render("room", { roomId: req.params.room });
    });
    
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      socket.on("join-room", (roomId, userId) => {
        socket.join(roomId);
        socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit("user-connected", userId);
        // messages
        socket.on("message", (message) => {
          //send message to the same room
          io.to(roomId).emit("createMessage", message);
        });
    
        socket.on("disconnect", () => {
          socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit("user-disconnected", userId);
        });
      });
    });
    
    server.listen(3030);

I am really new to nodejs so any constructive criticism or help would be greatly appreciated :)
```

EDIT:

here is script.js where peerjs is running and socket (this file also deals with camera functionality, and message functionality. I am assuming this is where the error happens since it does not give me an exact line where the error occurs)(script.js)

```
const socket = io("/");
const videoGrid = document.getElementById("video-grid");
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
  path: "/peerjs",
  host: "/",
  port: "432",
});
let myVideoStream;
const myVideo = document.createElement("video");
myVideo.muted = true;
const peers = {};
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    myVideoStream = stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);
    myPeer.on("call", (call) => {
      call.answer(stream);
      const video = document.createElement("video");
      call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
      });
    });

    socket.on("user-connected", (userId) => {
      connectToNewUser(userId, stream);
    });
    // input value
    let text = $("input");
    // when press enter send message
    $("html").keydown(function (e) {
      if (e.which == 13 && text.val().length !== 0) {
        socket.emit("message", text.val());
        text.val("");
      }
    });
    socket.on("createMessage", (message) => {
      $("ul").append(`<li class="message"><b>user</b><br/>${message}</li>`);
      scrollToBottom();
    });
  });

socket.on("user-disconnected", (userId) => {
  if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close();
});

myPeer.on("open", (id) => {
  socket.emit("join-room", ROOM_ID, id);
});

function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
  const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream);
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
  });
  call.on("close", () => {
    video.remove();
  });

  peers[userId] = call;
}

function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
    video.play();
  });
  videoGrid.append(video);
}

const scrollToBottom = () => {
  var d = $(".main__chat_window");
  d.scrollTop(d.prop("scrollHeight"));
};

const muteUnmute = () => {
  const enabled = myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled;
  if (enabled) {
    myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
    setUnmuteButton();
  } else {
    setMuteButton();
    myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true;
  }
};

const playStop = () => {
  console.log("object");
  let enabled = myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled;
  if (enabled) {
    myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;
    setPlayVideo();
  } else {
    setStopVideo();
    myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true;
  }
};

const setMuteButton = () => {
  const html = `
    <i class="fas fa-microphone"></i>
    <span>Mute</span>
  `;
  document.querySelector(".main__mute_button").innerHTML = html;
};

const setUnmuteButton = () => {
  const html = `
    <i class="unmute fas fa-microphone-slash"></i>
    <span>Unmute</span>
  `;
  document.querySelector(".main__mute_button").innerHTML = html;
};

const setStopVideo = () => {
  const html = `
    <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
    <span>Stop Video</span>
  `;
  document.querySelector(".main__video_button").innerHTML = html;
};

const setPlayVideo = () => {
  const html = `
  <i class="stop fas fa-video-slash"></i>
    <span>Play Video</span>
  `;
  document.querySelector(".main__video_button").innerHTML = html;
};
```

Comment: What does the client side code of the connection look like?

Comment: Also, note that `app.get("/:room", ...)` will match ALL top level URLs so this may conflict with any other top level URL now or in the future as you want to add more to your service.  This is generally not an advisable thing to do.

Comment: I added my only other js file

Comment: Is `const socket = io("/");` connecting to the port 3030 that your server is listening on?  Are you using the identical version of socket.io in client and server? A typical cause of the type of error you're seeing is mismatched socket.io versions.

Comment: I don't use socket-io-client for this project. Or at least the tutorial did not. Is there a better way I could be doing this?

Comment: How are you loading the socket.io library into your browser page?  Please show the `<script>` tag that loads it.